# Given [supposition]

Tags: american-english, british-english

I'm going to articulate a sentence which says:

> "Given that our society had the technology to do it......"

Is it syntactically correct? I have a couple of doubts, one related to the first conjunction ("that") is it required? and as I'm mentioning an hypothesis is it correct to use "had" in this case ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: As far as it goes, *Given that our society had the technology to do it…* is just fine… but whatever came after could spoil it completely.

Whether you need *had* or *has* depends on the tense you're describing.

FYI *articulate a sentence* might not be strictly wrong and it's more strange than right.